# Cabinet Recommendation for 2 NVIDIA GTX 1070

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

I have 2 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, one of them is ASUS GeForce GTX 1070 ROG STRIX, and the other is ASUS DUAL GTX 1070. I have a HB Bridge which I am not able to connect because the strix one is wider than dual. I have placed the strix one in the 1st PCIe slot and then the dual one in the 2nd one, I cannot put the strix one in 2nd slot as my cabinet's hard disk bay blocks it. The only way to connect the bridge is to put the dual one 1st and the strix one 2nd. I need a cabinet that is large enough to support in this configuration.
My PC Details:
Cabinet - Antec GX500 Window
Mobo - ASUS Z170 PROGAMING.

Comment: There's a massive, massive, massive variety of cases that will fit these cards–you happen to have one of the few that doesn't. Anything that lists the ability to accommodate two 29.8cm cards will be fine. Have you got any further requirements? Budget, I/O, expansion, etc.? If not, it's just a matter of taste at that point; I'm happy to give you some recommendations, but for the most part, it'll just be "well reviewed and I think it looks pretty."

Comment: @JMY1000 I have a budget of 5000-6000 INR and I have about 3 HDD and 1 SSD

Comment: Not super familiar with availability in India, but [browse this list and see if anything catches your eye.](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/case/#X=0,7902&J=3,20&K=1,12&m=337,50,11,716,106,58,62,94,229,51,63,46,56) I personally have used the S340 and enjoy it very much.